# Sum columns with similar names in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Relatively new to SQL and want to shorten a query I’m using.

The goal is to add the total spent in one year and compare it to the next year. However, the column names are all formatted “Spend_YYYYMM” so “Spend_202102.”

Currently, my solution is just to add all 12 columns up:

```
SELECT
“Full_Name”,
(“Spend_202001”+”Spend_202002”...) AS “2020 Total”,
(“Spend_201901”+”Spend_201902”...) AS “2019 Total”
FROM “Customers”
WHERE “2019 Total” > “2020 Total”;
```

So is there a way to look for columns where it starts with “Spend_2019” and add them up without having to type all 12 columns out? Or is what I have the only way we can really do this?

(Sorry for all the superfluous quotes, it’s apparently how our DB works with SQL.)

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Why do you have a separate column for each year/month combination?  Wouldn't it make more sense to put things like the year and month values in the data itself?  That way (A) you don't need to change the database schema and all the code every month and (B) you can just sum your rows instead of trying to dynamically sum columns.

Comment: Definitely not ideal the way it is, that’s for sure. But I’m basically pulling from a database that I don’t manage, so this isn’t my architecture. Kind of a great lesson for if I do end up being the sole manager of one. Thank you!

Comment: Not ideal? You have spreadsheet, not a database.

Answer (score 1):

First, do not use identifiers that need to be escaped.

Second, your data model is weak.  You should have separate *rows* for the different years.

But, the answer to your question is a MySQL extension of the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT Full_Name,
       (Spend_202001 + Spend_202002 ...) AS Total_2020,
       (Spend_201901 + Spend_201902 ...) AS Total_2019
FROM Customers
HAVING Total_2019 > Total_2020 ;
```

Comment: Very important suggestions.@JPFichera you might consider these.

Comment: Hey there! Unfortunately I don’t manage this DB and am just pulling what’s available to me. But could you elaborate on what you mean by “identifiers that are escaped”? That phrase is new to me and these are some really great tips in case I do end up getting more involved as I work with this data. Thank you!

Comment: @JPFichera . . . Don't use quotes for identifiers.  You'll get a syntax error if you try `2020 Total`.  Hence, I added an underscore.